# Filling an Area in visual studio C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, graphics

I'm drawing a circle in C# and i have divided it into some parts,i want to fill different parts with different colors,is there anyway to do this? and how?i tried using fillpie() but i couldn't get the arguments to work.

here is the code:

```
            int r = 150;
            g.DrawEllipse(Pens.Black, 300 - r, 250 - r, 2 * r, 2 * r);

            if (p != 0)
                g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, 300, 250, 300 + r, 250);
            double sum;
            sum = 0.0;
            for (int j = 0; j < p; j++)
                sum += data[j].value;
            double angle;
            angle = 0.0;
            for (int i = 0; i < p; i++)
            {
                angle += (double)(data[i].value / sum) * 2.0 * Math.PI;
                textBox1.Text += sum.ToString() + " : " + angle.ToString() + ":" + Math.Cos(angle).ToString() + "\r\n";
                g.DrawLine(Pens.Black, 300, 250, 300 + (int)(Math.Cos(angle) * r), 250 - (int)(Math.Sin(angle) * r));
            //g.FillPie(Brushes.Black, 300-r , 250 - r, r, r ,(float)(angle),(float)(angle+ (data[i].value   / sum) * 2.0 * Math.PI));

            }
```

this actually divides the circle into different parts,i don't know how to fill them

the commented line is where i

Comment: What arguments have you tried? Maybe you would like to edit your question to show some code that you have?

Comment: Winforms or WPF? Please show some code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposing you are using WinForms, the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dw5wshbd.aspx) hase some nice and easy example for the FillPie() method.

```
public void FillPieRectangle(PaintEventArgs e)
{

    // Create solid brush.
    SolidBrush redBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);

    // Create rectangle for ellipse.
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 200, 100);

    // Create start and sweep angles.
    float startAngle =  0.0F;
    float sweepAngle = 45.0F;

    // Fill pie to screen.
    e.Graphics.FillPie(redBrush, rect, startAngle, sweepAngle);
}
```

**EDIT:**

It looks like you actually want to draw some kind of pie chart, but your code looks way to complicated. Take a look at [this article](http://codeguru.earthweb.com/columns/dotnet/article.php/c6145) that might give you some help.

Answer (score 0):

```
e.Graphics.FillPie(new SolidBrush(Color.Red,0, 0,45,45,0,30)
```